# what is "data" in primerfaces marker?

Tags: primefaces

I'm making a marker for a google map in primefaces and I'd like to set the icon. But the constructor for marker that allows setting the icon requires a parameter called "data". I'm not finding data being documented anywhere although one place I found says that it gets passed to super(). I can work around this by using a different constructor and then making a call to setIcon but that's two steps instead of one. So, any idea of what data is and how to safely make the call to the constructor that sets the icon?

Comment: Did you try putting something in the data parameter and see if it renders to the html somewhere?

Comment: Or look at the source?

Comment: http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/data/gmap/infoWindow.xhtml